# ¿Cómo hacer que una variable en Javascript sea un vinculo?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Tengo el siguiente JSON

```
{
   "label": "Hola",
   "value": {
    "input": {
    "url": "www.google.com"
       }
     }
},
```

El valor de `label` lo estoy almacenando en una variable que se llama `"Direccion"` en Javascript. Y estoy pintando esa variable en un HTML. Necesito que al momento de hacer click en esa variable me mande a la dirección que dice el JSON como `url`. ¿Cómo lo podría hacer?

Estoy pintando la varible de la siguiente manera:
-En mi HTML

```
<div id="direcciones">
</div>
```

-En mi Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('direcciones').innerHTML= `La siguiente variable te llevara a una url ${Direccion}`
```

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cómo estás pintando las variables en el HTML? Incluye eso en tu pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo listo!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo con un `<a>` asi:

```js
var json = {
   "label": "Hola",
   "value": {
    "input": {
    "url": "www.google.com"
       }
     }
};

var Direccion = json.label;
var url = json.value.input.url;
document.getElementById("direcciones").innerHTML = "<a href='https://" + url + "'>" + Direccion + "</a>";
```

```html
<div id="direcciones"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo también mediante el método [**`createElement`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) del DOM. Aunque es un poco más verboso (y... depende), tiene sus ventajas.

```js
var mJson = {
  "label": "Hola",
  "value": {
    "input": {
      "url": "www.google.com"
    }
  }
};

var mDiv = document.getElementById('direcciones');
var a = document.createElement('a');
var aText = document.createTextNode(mJson.label);
var aHref = 'https://'+mJson.value.input.url;

a.appendChild(aText);
a.href = aHref;
a.title ='Click para ir a Google';
mDiv.appendChild(a);
console.log(a);
```

```html
<div id="direcciones"></div>
```

Si quieres analizar las diferencias entre usar `createElement` o `innerHTML`, puedes ver las respuestas a la pregunta [*Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2946656/5587982) planteada en Stackoverflow en inglés.

Answer (score -1):

en javascript para enlazar a un sitio externo, se hace así:

`href.location = "http://www.ejemplo.com"`

Mete esa funcionalidad js en el HTML con el evento `onclick`

Comment: Mi estimado Daniel tu respuesta no es lo que solicita el OP, ya que requiere sacar la URL de un `JSON` y no ponerlo de forma estática, te invito a observar la respuesta de @alanfcm.